# How can I add a DOI or link to my article on Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, online-publication, google-scholar

My article was published in a very mainstream and widely-read journal several months ago and has been available online since then, but I cannot find it on Google Scholar. I tried adding the article manually, but I cannot find anywhere to put either the article's DOI or a link to the online version. It would be convenient to allow people to link directly to the article from the Google Scholar entry. Is there any way to do so?

The Google Scholar [help page](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) says

> If you're an individual author, it works best to simply upload your paper to your website, e.g., www.example.edu/~professor/jpdr2009.pdf; and add a link to it on your publications page, such as www.example.edu/~professor/publications.html.

But I don't see anywhere to include a link on the "Add article manually" page.

Comment: I think that google will use it's crawlers to find the link to the pdf. That's why you should add a link on your personal/institute website to the pdf (uploaded on your own website or directly to the publisher, if it is open access). The link will be found by google's crawlers (during their regular site checking crawlers), and then - hopefully - google's algorithms will add the link to the pdf on google scholar.

Comment: As I understood not all journals allow Google to access their publications, even if it is an open access journal. If you can upload your paper to another accessible location - it should appear in the scholar eventually.

Comment: Just to clarify - can you find the article using Google (not Google Scholar)?

Comment: @Martin Yes, I can.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with other posters that it is best to upload your paper to your website. Either post the full paper with title page, citation, etc., on a website within your institutional address, or on a known repository like a pre-print server such as https://psyarxiv.com.

Comment: "Yes, agree with the above" - the OP should agree with the above (with what?), or you agree with the above - but _what_ exactly? The help page or the comments? This is not a chat room or a regular forum - please be precise.